# SQL- how to retrieve by similar dates

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, oracle12c

Okay, so I have a table with a user_id column and a submitted_dtm column.

I want to find instances where users submitted multiple records within 1 day of each other, and count how many times that has happened.

I've tried something like

```
select * from table_t t where 
(select count(*) from table_t t2 where 
t.user_id = t2.user_id and
t.pk!=t2.pk and
t.submitted_dtm between t2.submitted_dtm-.5 and t2.submitted_dtm+.5)>0;
```

The problem is that this query returns a result for each record in a date group.  Instead, I just want a result per date group. Ideally, I'd just get the count in that group.

That is, if I have 6 records:

```
user_id     submitted_dtm
--------------------------
1            12/04/2017 1:15
1            12/04/2017 5:50
2            11/25/2017 2:00
2            11/25/2017 3:25
2            11/25/2017 6:05
2            10/06/2017 4:00
```

I want 2 results, a count of 2 and a count of 3.

Is it possible to do this in sql?

Comment: This can be done in plain SQL. How difficult it is, though, depends on two things. One is easy: What is your Oracle database version? If you don't know for sure, run `select * from v$version`. No, check that; run the `select` statement even if you are sure. And post the full version number (for example, 12.1.0.2.0 rather than "12c"). The other thing is the meaning of your problem. What do you want counted if the user submits something at 3 pm on one day, and then five more times, six hours apart, for a total of six submissions? (Continued below)

Comment: Is that one occurrence? Or is that counted as "five" because there are really five submissions that were then followed by another submission within less than 24 hours? Or is it only two - because the first submission opens a 24 hour window, the next three are in that window, but the fifth is not, and it opens its own, new window? All three options (which are very different from each other, even with the same inputs) are valid and meaningful for different problems. So, please clarify. (Continued below)

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean by "within 1 day". Do you mean "during the same calendar day", or can that go over day boundaries and instead it means "within 24 hours, regardless of calendar date"? And if so, does "within 24 hours" mean the difference is STRICTLY less than 24 hours, or does EXACTLY 24 hours also count as "within 24 hours"?

Comment: The version is 12.1.0.2.0, 64 bit.

You brought up some issues I hadn't considered. I guess what I really want is the number of times where a user has submitted more than 1 records in 1 calendar day, inclusive of the ends. 

So in your example of 3pm and then 5 more, 6 hours apart, it would count 3pm and 9pm as a group of 2, and then 3am, 9am, 3pm, and 9pm as a group of 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on Dessma's answer.

```
select user_id, trunc(submitted_dtm), count(1)
  from table_t
 group by user_id, trunc(submitted_dtm)
having count(1) > 1;
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d03/1)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the trunc() function. This works great!

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, you can solve such problems easily with the `match_recognize` clause. Link to documentation (with examples) below; my only note about the solution below is that I left the date in DATE data type, especially important if the output is used in further computations. If it isn't, you can wrap within `TO_CHAR()` with whatever format model is appropriate for your users.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956

```
with
  inputs ( user_id, submitted_dtm ) as (
    select 1, to_date('12/04/2017 1:15', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 1, to_date('12/04/2017 5:50', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 2, to_date('11/25/2017 2:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 2, to_date('11/25/2017 3:25', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 2, to_date('11/25/2017 6:05', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 2, to_date('10/06/2017 4:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins below this line. Use your actual table and column names.
select user_id, submitted_dtm, cnt
from   inputs
match_recognize(
  partition by user_id
  order by     submitted_dtm
  measures     trunc(a.submitted_dtm) as submitted_dtm,
               count(*) as cnt
  pattern      ( a b+ )
  define       b as trunc(submitted_dtm) = trunc(a.submitted_dtm)
);

   USER_ID SUBMITTED_DTM              CNT
---------- ------------------- ----------
         1 2017-12-04 00:00:00          2
         2 2017-11-25 00:00:00          3
```

Comment: Ooh, neat! I'm going to have to bookmark that for later reading.

Comment: @kfinity - I didn't try, but I believe if you google for "Oracle match_recognize site:stackoverflow.com" you will find many examples of how this new clause (new in 12.1) can be used a very diverse array of problems. I am in continuous admiration of its power and flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have data to test it but I suspect something like this would do the trick :

```
SELECT user_id,To_char(t.submitted_dtm, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), COUNT(*)
  FROM table_t t
 INNER JOIN table_t t2
    ON t.user_id = t2.user_id
   AND t.pk != t2.pk
   AND t.submitted_dtm BETWEEN t2.submitted_dtm - .5 AND
       t2.submitted_dtm + .5
 GROUP BY user_id,To_char(t.submitted_dtm, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: The whole t2 inner join is not needed here, IMO.

Comment: kfinity That's absolutely right, I pretty much got lost in my mind writing the query in notepad. SQL Fiddle looks like a nice tool, I'll definitely try to use that next time : )

Answer (score 1):

This is a general idea of how to get the instances.

```
select user_id, t1.submitted_dtm t1submitted, t2.submitted_dtm t2submtted 
from table_t t1 join table_t t2 using (user_id)
where t2.submitted_dtm > t1.submitted_dtm 
and t2.submitted_dtm - t1.submitted_dtm <= 1;
```

The last line could be modified somehow depending on what you mean by `within a day`.

To count the instances, create a derived table from the above and select count(*) from it.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to make sure that t2.submitted_dtm > t1.submitted_dtm?

Comment: How does this deal with five or six submissions from the same user, all within one day from each other?

Comment: FYI, for Oracle SQL, the join syntax would be `join table_t t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id`

Comment: @kfinity, we all learn something new every day.  Today, you learn that oracle supports this syntax.

Comment: Haha, fair! The first time I tried it, I still had table aliases on the USING column and it complained. But when I copied & pasted your code, it worked fine.